# Accessing Office 365 ProPlus OneDrive folder using the official Python SDK

Tags: python, authentication, configuration, office365, onedrive

We are currently trying to access a folder of an Office 365 ProPlus tenant using the official OneDrive SDK for Python (https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-python). One of our clients would like to use a OneDrive folder as a way of storing and sharing programmatically generated files, therefore, we would like to provide basic file operations.

We have a working solution for a personal OneDrive account, however, when we try to apply the same approach for *their* OneDrive, we face an issue during the authentication process.

We asked them to register the application in the Azure AD following the steps in the official documentation. Next, they sent us the redirect URI, client ID and client secret that we included in our script. We are trying to use the following code:

```
redirect_uri = 'REDIRECT_URI'
client_secret = 'CLIENT_SECRET'
client_id='CLIENT_ID'
discovery_uri = 'https://api.office.com/discovery/'
auth_server_url='https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize'
auth_token_url='https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token'

http_provider = onedrivesdk.HttpProvider()
auth_provider = onedrivesdk.AuthProvider(http_provider,
                                client_id,
                                auth_server_url=auth_server_url,
                                auth_token_url=auth_token_url)

auth_url = auth_provider.get_auth_url(redirect_uri)
code = GetAuthCodeServer.get_auth_code(auth_url, redirect_uri)
```

However, we get the following error message when executing the last line:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "onedrive-test.py", line 25, in 
>           code = GetAuthCodeServer.get_auth_code(auth_url, redirect_uri)
>         File "/home/username/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/onedrivesdk/helpers/GetAuthCodeServer.py",
>   line 60, in get_auth_code
>           s = GetAuthCodeServer((host_address, port), code_acquired, GetAuthCodeRequestHandler)
>         File "/home/username/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/onedrivesdk/helpers/GetAuthCodeServer.py",
>   line 76, in **init**
>           HTTPServer.**init**(self, server_address, RequestHandlerClass)
>         File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 453, in **init**
>           self.server_bind()
>         File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/server.py", line 136, in server_bind
>           socketserver.TCPServer.server_bind(self)
>         File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 467, in server_bind
>           self.socket.bind(self.server_address)
>       socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

We also tried opening the auth_url manually, which took us one step further, but still could not authenticate the application with the following error:

> AADSTS50020: User account 'USER ACCOUNT' from identity provider
>   'live.com' does not exist in tenant 'TENANT NAME' and cannot access
>   the application 'CLIENT ID' in that tenant. The account needs to be
>   added as an external user in the tenant first. Sign out and sign in
>   again with a different Azure Active Directory user account.

We have two questions:

1. What might casue the first error? This is the comment (see below) that can be found in the readme of the SDK about using the GetAuthCodeServer class. It seems to us that the server cannot be run. Are there any not explicitly defined dependencies that we should be aware of before trying to run the webserver? (We are running the script on Ubuntu 18.10)

> If you want to remove some of that manual work, you can
>   use the helper class GetAuthCodeServer. That helper class spins up a
>   webserver, so this method cannot be used on all environments.

2. With respect to the second issue, can you recommend proper material for configuring OneDrive for Business for our use-case? We went through a lot of documentation, but after long hours of research, we still could not find the correct way to fix that issue, especially since we do not have direct acces to the tenant and we cannot easily experiment with things. We would need to give a step-by-step cookbook to our client to set up everything on their side.

Any help would be much appreciated! :)